# Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource (REST API SharePoint Designer)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, permissions, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have created a workflow with SharePoint Designer 2013 for SharePoint Online Portal.

My workflow works with my account with full permissions but it doesn't for other users with Edit access. I created a new user with Edit access and it works but not for the rest 100 users. The workflow fails at the very beginning where I put the following value in a local variable:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items([%Current Item:ID%])/attachmentfiles
```

I get the message regarding the permissions. Again this only happens for the existing users and not for the new one I created with the same permissions as them.

I added this into an App Step to check again and still doesn't work.

Does someone now why this doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure that you have configured the workflow permission correctly as mentioned at **[Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-workflow-suspended-unauthorized/)**

Comment: you configured the App Step well? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the current user added to a group that has the following permission:

> [Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model
>   or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-workflow-suspended-unauthorized/#access-denied-you-do-not-have-permission-to-perform-this-action-or-access-this-resource)

**Steps**

- In Site collection permission,
- Click on the Permission Level.
- Edit your Permission Level,
- Go down to `Site Permission` section, check

> `Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site.`

For more details, Please check **[SharePoint Workflow Permissions](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-workflow-suspended-unauthorized/)**

Comment: If you run the workflow code in an app step your workflow principal needs the same permissions.

Comment: this is helped me fixed me issue. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Please check once does Proxy account have sufficient access.